# Partitioning line items in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, partition

There are three values for column named `custom_value`, Viable, Non-Viable or none. I want to partition the Viable values because it can have multiple Viables. (To understand this Viable choice is just multiple forms of a paper to be approved for a process. A person can apply multiple times and be accepted multiple times).

```
Select *
From Sample.database.tbl_custom
Where ben_ID in ('568764','798426') AND ID = '123456'
Order By ID;

Create Partition Function viable_non_viable_line_items(char20)
--I am stuck with what should I do to partition off these multiple forms of a paper.
```

Comment: Why are you partitioning the table?

Comment: Partitioning is something you would do to segregate current data from infrequently accessed data in tables that are many gigs in size. Is that your use-case here?

Comment: Well there are 86 rows that come up with query. I was going to do it because it was suggested to me for the task. By the comments it seems I need to do something else.

Comment: Table partitioning is not what you want. Explain what the problem is you're trying to solve and someone can probably suggest a better solution.

Comment: Sounds like you *might* have been pointed to window functions with a `PARTITION BY` clause, but it's really hard to say without you telling us what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_VIALBILITY (CHAR(20))
AS RANGE LEFT 
FOR VALUES ('Viable', 'Non-Viable' 'none')
```

To enforce the partitionning mechanism, add a CHECK constraint to the table as :

```
ALTER tbl_custom 
   ADD CONSTRAINT CK_VIALBILITY
   CHECK (custom_value IN ('Viable', 'Non-Viable' 'none'));
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server partition supports a single column only as a Partition Key. If you want to support multiple columns in a Partition Key then you have to define the computed column first then apply the partitioning on that column.